# Make a POST form-data with React to upload an image

Tags: reactjs, axios, postman, nestjs

I am trying to upload an image within my ReactJS service to my NestJS API service, through my API, but it's not working yet. This is the React code:

First the form:

```
<div>
 <input type="file" name="urlpromo" value={urlpromo} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

and the functions:

```
changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}

submitBaner = (e) => {
        var bodyFormData = new FormData();

        bodyFormData.append('file', this.state.urlpromo);
        
        let config = {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
              }
        }
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(bodyFormData)
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/images/upload', bodyFormData,config)
    }
```

The thing is that before I was sending images, only with JSON body, it was working fine, but now with form-data, I cant make it work. This is how I can upload an image with Postman:

[image]

When I try to make it work, the function console log prints this:

```
FormData {}__proto__: FormData
```

What I am doing wrong, how should I work with this form-data?

Comment: Is this working from postman?

Comment: Don't try logging the `FormData` instance, it is not serialisable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag), `<input type="file">` is *uncontrolled* due to its read-only value.

One option is to use a [*ref*](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to track the `<input>` element and the `files` property to access the `File`

```js
// in your constructor
this.urlPromoRef = React.createRef()
```

```html
<div>
 <input type="file" ref={this.urlPromoRef} />
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

and in your submit handler

```js
e.preventDefault()
const bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append('file', this.urlPromoRef.files[0]);

// no need for extra headers
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/images/upload', bodyFormData)
```

---

Another option is to simply pass the `<form>` itself into the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) constructor.

```html
<form onSubmit={this.submitBaner}>
  <div>
    <input type="file" name="urlpromo" /> <!-- must have a name -->
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
submitBaner = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const bodyFormData = new FormData(e.target); // pass in the form

  axios.post('http://localhost:3000/images/upload', bodyFormData)
}
```

---

Finally, you may be able to use something like your original code but with a special check for `<input type="file">`. Eg

```js
changeHandler = (e) => {
  const el = e.target
  this.setState({
    [el.name]: el.type === "file" ? el.files[0] : el.value
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, with the ChangeHandler thing I fixed it